# Right choice of accuracy metric or loss function

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, loss-function

I am developing a predictive model in sports vertical. As the game will progress, my model will predict the **winning probability** of each team playing.

The problem I am facing is to what metric would be appropriate to quantify accuracy for the model.

What I have in mind to quantify accuracy is as follows :

Consider `n` matches for which my model predicts the winning probability of Team A at time instance `t1, t2 ... tn`. For each match, I will quantify the loss as the hinge loss at that time. i.e. if **probability** greater than **threshold** and team_A actually won, then accurate.

As the game progresses, model gets new info and I can expect the model performance to improve, so I thought about giving weights to loss function acc. to **Time of prediction** also. i.e. if model predicts wrongly at la**ter point of the game** then it should be **penalized heavily**.

But I think it can be better. Any leads on the apt. loss function for this is highly appreciated.

Hoping to learn something great from the answers.